# "Visual studio 2008 SP1" ADO.NET Entity Data Model template not found

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, ado.net

I have installed Visual Studio Team System 2008 Architecture version: 9.0.30729.1 SP and Microsoft Net Framework 3.5 SP1.

When I'm going to add a new item I can't find ADO.NET Entity Data Model template.

What's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes! Selecting .NET Framework 3.5. Check if you have also installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Comment: Hi, I am using VS 2008 Professional with .NET Framework 3.5, but I still don't have the template. What can I do about it? I hv reinstalled VS 2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5, still can't see ADO.NET Entity Data Model template.

Comment: Make sure you are selecting Framework 3.5 on project dialog.

Comment: It works for me! For the benefit of others (cos I just found out how to do it), "Right Click on your project >> Properties >> "Application" tab >> Target Framework". I think it's cos my project was previously developed using VS2005, before I upgrade it to VS2008. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SUMMARY**
There seem to be multiple causes of this problem as many of the other answers indicate.

1. Make sure Framework 3.5 sp1 is installed first
2. Make sure Visual Studio 2008 sp1 is installed
3. Makes sure the project targets the 3.5 framework
4. A data model is added to an existing project, not a separate project type

**END SUMMARY**

You *may* be looking at the wrong level.  An Entity Framework Data Model is something that you add to a project, it is not a separate project type.

Right-click on an existing project
Select Add,
New Item

And then select ADO.Net Entity Data Model...

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have [VS2008 sp1 (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)).
I had .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed but not the VS2008 SP1.
...at least that is what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure you also run the Service Pack Preparation tool that listed in the Important section on the download page for VS2008 SP1. This was required for it to work on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

So, to recap:

Requires Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (includes .Net Framework 3.5 SP1)

You must be working with a **.Net Framework 3.5** project

In the Solution Explorer, right click and select "Add"->"New Item"

For ease of finding it, select the "Data" item in the left hand side treeview

Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model and specify a name in the textbox below

Answer (score 2):

I think most of you guys are confusing sp1 for .net with service pack of vs2008. very likely you all have .net 3.5 sp1. You need to have both .net 3.5 sp1 + vs2008 sp1....the later would take a lot of time to download and install depending on your net speed..

try it and this problem would be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but my solution ended up being simple: my project was defaulting to a .Net 2.0 project, and it needed to be set to .Net 3.5 before it would offer me Entity Framework options in the Add New Item box.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had Visual Studio SP1 installed and the .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 applied.

I downloaded the Visual Studio SP1 ISO and burnded it to a DVD.

I found that I had to uninstall Visual Studio and then reinstall. Only then could I apply the SP1 from the DVD.

My Visual Studio was a relatively fresh installation. I did install .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and ASP.NET MVC 1.0 before trying to upgrade to the SP1. These may have created a conflict with the SP1 upgrade.

ISO: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=27673c47-b3b5-4c67-bd99-84e525b5ce61&displaylang=en

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to install latest version of ADO.NET Entity Framework form below link:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=15DB9989-1621-444D-9B18-D1A04A21B519&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The thing is that ASP.NET MVC should be installed after .NET 3.5 SP1 and  VS2008 SP1, if you installed it before - try to deinstall ASP.NET MVC, .NET 3.5 SP1 and  VS2008 SP1 and then install it in the right order.

Thanks,
Arty

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and then it worked!

Find the SP1 here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=27673c47-b3b5-4c67-bd99-84e525b5ce61&displaylang=en